# How to stop function or animation laggy/buggy thing?

Tags: jquery

I am not sure if my title is correct but what I am trying to do is to stop fadeToggle();

When I click once it fadeIn and second click fadeOut my overlay but when I click like insane maniac fast on the button it fadeIn and fadeOut really slow and buggy...

What I want to do is to prevent this to look buggy and since I am learning basics, I do not know how, yet... So please if anyone could tell me ?

Here's sample:

```
$('#overlay-trigger, div#overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('div#overlay').fadeToggle();
});
```

[JS Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/uTtYA/)

So as it is noticable I have an button named #overlay-trigger. On click of that button an overlay fadeIn();

After that click on overlay hides its self...

So if you just keep clicking fast you will see what is wrong with it... it stucks, slow, laggy I dont know correct phrase...

Help me please and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[:animated](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/)** selector..

```
$('#overlay-trigger, div#overlay').on('click', function() {
    var $overlay = $('div#overlay');
    if( !$overlay.is(':animated')){
        $overlay.fadeToggle();
    }
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uTtYA/2/)**

Comment: Interesting method! :D 

But I do not understand what this part means:
An exclamation mark (!) 

thanks tho... it works as well, and it is interesting

Comment: It is a not operator .. Checks if the div is not currently animating , only then toggle

Comment: what it means is - if element is not animating.. then fadetoggle()-.. good solution also.. downfall is when a user doesn't want to wait until animation is complete first to toggle again..

Comment: @wirey .. That may be a point to be noted ... But it depends upon how the OP wants to handle it !!

Comment: @wirey your example is good and fast but still if user click fast enough he can reveal div#overlay by clicking somewhere on background after it has been revealed once.

Sushanth-- this works great and user is not possible to reveal it by any chance, except to click on button again. Just like I wanted.

Both solutions are great but I will accept this answer as best solution for my thingy... :)

Answer (score 2):

Use stop like:

```
$('div#overlay').stop().fadeToggle();
```

More info: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2):

you need to use jQuery's [.stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) method with the animations, passing in the needed arguments ex. `.stop(true)`, `.stop(true,true)` etc

```
$('#overlay-trigger, div#overlay').on('click', function() {
    $('div#overlay').stop().fadeToggle();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nPShy/

Comment: I see... I tried this stop() and I put it on wrong place only... The place where I put it was after fadeToggle(); so it didn't worked cause it stoped the fade animation.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Using [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) **may** solve your problem. From the jQuery API docs:

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

The `one()` function works by unbinding the click event after it's fist invocation. To modify the less possible from your code, just use it like the following:

```
$('#overlay-trigger, div#overlay').one('click', function() {
    $('div#overlay').fadeToggle();
});
```

I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: Because dumb me deleted an important part from the example. See now after edition

Comment: Ah... yeh I see now. But it's not doing required job.
It does works but only once. One time fadeIn and one time fadeOut and after that, it stops working.

But it's good to learn so thanks.

Comment: That would prevent frantic/insane movements from your users by restricting the effect for one execution.